# Apache - .htaccess - Redirect only URLs ending with "/feed"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect only URLs ending on `/feed` (constant 404s - from Amazon servers? - using a wrong url). How can I configure the redirect?

Currently my .htaccess file looks like this. I am trying to add a folder /category before the incoming url.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 /mobile-home /
Redirect 301 /destinations-3/greeter-destinations/ /greeter-destinations/
Redirect 301 /destinations-3/ /category/destinations/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content/
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/feed$ content/category/$1/feed [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The 2 "#" lines were taken from another thread but they do not have any effect.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will perform a permanent redirect for URLs matching your pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^destinations/(.*)/feed$ /category/destination/$1/feed [L,R=301]
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. 
But the folder left of /feed is dynamic (any country name):
the url called is /destinations/(country)/feed and should become /category/destinations/(country)/feed. In other words: add /category before called url
How to do that?

Comment: You're welcome. I've just updated my answer to match your pattern, feel free to let me know if this works better.

Comment: HI Bruno,
thanks! I would love to say "done" but by any reason it is not.
I had to change your solution a little bit because the new url does not contain "destinations" but "destination". This is it now:
    RewriteRule ^destinations/(.*)/feed$ /category/destination/$1/feed [L,R=301]

Comment: Did you place my rule just after RewriteEngine On?

Comment: Sorry, this is the complete comment:
HI Bruno,
thanks! I would love to say "done" but by any reason it is not.
I had to change your solution a little bit because the new url does not contain "destinations" but "destination". This is it now:

    RewriteRule ^destinations/(.*)/feed$ /category/destination/$1/feed [L,R=301]

But if I get a call like /destinations/russia/feed the start page shows up. But if I call /category/destination/russia/feed I get the RSS feed.

Any idea?

Comment: This is the entire rewrite section in .htaccess:

    '<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    Redirect 301 /mobile-home /
    Redirect 301 /destinations-3/greeter-destinations/ /greeter-destinations/
    Redirect 301 /destinations-3/ /category/destinations/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^destinations/(.*)/feed$ /category/destination/$1/feed     [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>'

Comment: You should place the rule just after RewriteEngine On

Comment: OK, I'll try next

Comment: Like that?
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^destinations/(.*)/feed$ /category/destination/$1/feed [L,R=301]`

Does not work. I deactivated the 404 plugin and now get a 404 with the status line unchanged.

Comment: No, just after RewriteEngine On, so before RewriteBase.

Comment: Sorry, no change
404: https://www.internationalgreeter.org/destinations/sweden/feed
ok: https://internationalgreeter.org/category/destination/sweden/feed

Comment: I can have a look, I've just e-mailed you a few minute ago.

Comment: I tried this and it worked:
Redirect 301 /destinations/sweden/feed https://internationalgreeter.org/category/destination/sweden/feed
but it is not dynamic....

Comment: Sorry,, did not read your previous comment. I'll answer by email